# uwsgi package build error in yocto imx6ul zeus

Tags: yocto, uwsgi, zeus

I´m trying add the package uwsgi to fsl-image-machine-test image using bitbake,

The depends are correctly added in the local.conf file

DEPENDS += " 
e2fsprogs 
python-pip 
python-six 
yajl 
"

When try compile the UWSGI package this error is showed:

```
WARNING: You have included the meta-openstack layer, but 'openstack' has not been enabled in your DISTRO_FEATURES. Some bbappend     files and preferred version setting may not take effect. See the meta-openstack README for details on enabling openstack support.
Loading cache...done.
Loaded 5375 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes...done.
Parsing of 3884 .bb files complete (3883 cached, 1 parsed). 5376 targets, 283 skipped, 1 masked, 0 errors.
WARNING: No recipes available for:
  /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-cloud-services/meta-openstack/recipes-devtools/qemu/qemu_2.%.bbappend
due to PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libc-locale = glibc-locale

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.44.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-18.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "imx6ulevk"
DISTRO               = "fsl-imx-xwayland"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "5.4-zeus"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            = "HEAD:d88d62c20d7d8da85f02edb170dae0280624ad7e"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          = "HEAD:2b5dd1eb81cd08bc065bc76125f2856e9383e98b"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:14f1a630a47375432f93c556927b879b51d84c4e"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:dbcc686f52c3c84db8cb86aa8973a4e373651b98"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:ca27d12e4964d1336e662bcc60184bbff526c857"
meta-bsp             
meta-sdk             
meta-ml              = "HEAD:63665ab70ca609451533101cded2a620b340768c"
meta-nxp-demo-experience = "HEAD:c7263d9f3cc7bbf44e7164ffeda494cf283d3dec"
meta-browser         = "HEAD:ee3be3b5986a4aa0e73df2204a625ae1fe5df37e"
meta-rust            = "HEAD:53bfa324891966a2daf5d36dc13d4a43725aebed"
meta-clang           = "HEAD:711e593d5984aad3bf35c51b7ac4482982bc16c7"
meta-gnome           
meta-networking      
meta-filesystems     = "HEAD:2b5dd1eb81cd08bc065bc76125f2856e9383e98b"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:21ce4c124d9a972d9122f87c64ac2773bf04c284"
meta-python2         = "HEAD:4400f9155ec193d028208cf0c66aeed2ba2b00ab"
meta-cloud-services  = "zeus:b8c25f63ab9124fe911165205d17808b9a7dead0"
meta-iot-cloud       = "zeus:d7db9c209e19ffab4bb6c4105308521369fd58f5"
meta-virtualization  = "zeus:7e5219669ff6f8e9c8c33ffd230e95a6b2b025f4"
meta-webserver       = "HEAD:2b5dd1eb81cd08bc065bc76125f2856e9383e98b"
meta-openstack       = "zeus:b8c25f63ab9124fe911165205d17808b9a7dead0"

Initialising tasks...NOTE: Marking Active Tasks
NOTE: Pruned 3168 inactive tasks, 1910 left
NOTE: Assign Weightings
NOTE: Compute totals (have 1 endpoint(s))
done.
Sstate summary: Wanted 8 Found 3 Missed 5 Current 471 (37% match, 98% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Setscene tasks completed
NOTE: Running task 1530 of 1910 (/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-cloud-services/meta-openstack/recipes-extended/    uwsgi/uwsgi_git.bb:do_install)
NOTE: recipe uwsgi-2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0: task do_install: Started
NOTE: uwsgi-2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0 do_install: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto/    imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus    /sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.66.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto/    imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto    /imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/    imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/python/python-six_1.12.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/    eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/    python-pip_19.2.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/    recipes-devtools/yajl/yajl_2.1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/    recipes-devtools/python/python-setuptools_41.2.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/    recipes-devtools/python/python_2.7.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/    recipes-devtools/python/python-native_2.7.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/    recipes-devtools/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs_1.45.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/    recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_9.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core    /glibc/glibc_2.30.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/    gcc-cross_9.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
NOTE: uwsgi-2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0 do_install: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: uwsgi-2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0 do_install: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['pseudo-native', 'quilt-native',     'patch-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'python-six', 'python-pip', 'yajl', 'python-setuptools-native', 'python', 'python-native',     'e2fsprogs', 'gcc-runtime', 'glibc', 'gcc-cross-arm', 'ncurses', 'sqlite3', 'openssl', 'libffi', 'bzip2', 'libxcrypt',     'readline', 'gdbm', 'db', 'zlib', 'xz-native', 'flex-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'linux-libc-headers', 'zlib-native',     'libmpc-native', 'mpfr-native', 'libtool-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'automake-native', 'autoconf-native',     'texinfo-dummy-native', 'gmp-native', 'libgcc', 'attr-native', 'unzip-native', 'attr', 'util-linux', 'opkg-utils',     'bzip2-native', 'readline-native', 'expat-native', 'openssl-native', 'gdbm-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'db-native',     'cryptodev-linux', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'm4-native', 'libpam', 'libcap-ng', 'bash-completion', 'ncurses-native', 'flex',     'cracklib']
+ cd /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/git
+ do_install
+ distutils_do_install
+ install -d /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

+ STAGING_INCDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include STAGING_LIBDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/    build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib     PYTHONPATH=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/    tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/    python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image --prefix=/usr --install-lib=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages --install-data=/usr/    share

running install

In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
                 from ./uwsgi.h:187,
                 from core/utils.c:1:
In function 'strncat',
    inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1727:3:
/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
  136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
core/utils.c:1707:20: note: length computed here
 1707 |  size_t with_len = strlen(with);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
                 from ./uwsgi.h:187,
                 from core/utils.c:1:
In function 'strncat',
    inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1732:2:
/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
  136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
core/utils.c:1732:2: note: length computed here
 1732 |  strncat(dst, ptr, strlen(ptr));
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

+ bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
+ [ -p /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/temp/fifo.16498 ]

+ printf %b\0 bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
+ exit 1
+ bb_exit_handler
+ ret=1
+ echo WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
+ exit 1

Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/    pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/    quilt-native_0.66.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools    /patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/    recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-openembedded/    meta-oe/recipes-devtools/python/python-six_1.12.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/    meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-pip_19.2.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/    imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/yajl/yajl_2.1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/    eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-setuptools_41.2.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/    eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python_2.7.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/    yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-native_2.7.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/    yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs_1.45.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto    /imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_9.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/    imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.30.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/    sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_9.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['pseudo-native', 'quilt-native', 'patch-native', 'pkgconfig-native',     'python-six', 'python-pip', 'yajl', 'python-setuptools-native', 'python', 'python-native', 'e2fsprogs', 'gcc-runtime', 'glibc',     'gcc-cross-arm', 'ncurses', 'sqlite3', 'openssl', 'libffi', 'bzip2', 'libxcrypt', 'readline', 'gdbm', 'db', 'zlib', 'xz-native',     'flex-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'linux-libc-headers', 'zlib-native', 'libmpc-native', 'mpfr-native', 'libtool-native',     'gnu-config-native', 'automake-native', 'autoconf-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'gmp-native', 'libgcc', 'attr-native',     'unzip-native', 'attr', 'util-linux', 'opkg-utils', 'bzip2-native', 'readline-native', 'expat-native', 'openssl-native',     'gdbm-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'db-native', 'cryptodev-linux', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'm4-native', 'libpam', 'libcap-ng',     'bash-completion', 'ncurses-native', 'flex', 'cracklib']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| + cd /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/git
| + do_install
| + distutils_do_install
| + install -d /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
| 
| + cd /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/git
| + do_install
| + distutils_do_install
| + install -d /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
| + STAGING_INCDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include STAGING_LIBDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/    build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib     PYTHONPATH=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/    tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/    python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image --prefix=/usr --install-lib=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages --install-data=/usr/    share
| 
| + STAGING_INCDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include STAGING_LIBDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/    build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib     PYTHONPATH=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/    tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/    python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image --prefix=/usr --install-lib=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages --install-data=/usr/    share
| running install
| 
| running install
| In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
|                  from ./uwsgi.h:187,
|                  from core/utils.c:1:
| In function 'strncat',
|     inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1727:3:
| /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
|   136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
| core/utils.c:1707:20: note: length computed here
|  1707 |  size_t with_len = strlen(with);
|       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
| 
| In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
|                  from ./uwsgi.h:187,
|                  from core/utils.c:1:
| In function 'strncat',
|     inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1727:3:
| /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
|   136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
| core/utils.c:1707:20: note: length computed here
|  1707 |  size_t with_len = strlen(with);
|       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
| In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
|                  from ./uwsgi.h:187,
|                  from core/utils.c:1:
| In function 'strncat',
|     inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1732:2:
| /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
|   136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
| core/utils.c:1732:2: note: length computed here
|  1732 |  strncat(dst, ptr, strlen(ptr));
|       |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 
| In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
|                  from ./uwsgi.h:187,
|                  from core/utils.c:1:
| In function 'strncat',
|     inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1732:2:
| /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
|   136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
| core/utils.c:1732:2: note: length computed here
|  1732 |  strncat(dst, ptr, strlen(ptr));
|       |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
| 
| cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
| + bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + [ -p /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/temp/fifo.16498 ]
| 
| + bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + [ -p /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/temp/fifo.16498 ]
| ERROR: 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + printf %b\0 bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + exit 1
| + bb_exit_handler
| + ret=1
| + echo WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| + exit 1
| 
| + printf %b\0 bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + exit 1
| + bb_exit_handler
| + ret=1
| + echo WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| + exit 1
| ERROR: Execution of '/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/temp/run.do_install.16498' failed with exit code 1:
| + cd /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/git
| + do_install
| + distutils_do_install
| + install -d /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
| + STAGING_INCDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include STAGING_LIBDIR=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/    build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib     PYTHONPATH=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/    tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/    python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image --prefix=/usr --install-lib=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages --install-data=/usr/    share
| running install
| In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
|                  from ./uwsgi.h:187,
|                  from core/utils.c:1:
| In function 'strncat',
|     inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1727:3:
| /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
|   136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
| core/utils.c:1707:20: note: length computed here
|  1707 |  size_t with_len = strlen(with);
|       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
| In file included from /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/string.h:494,
|                  from ./uwsgi.h:187,
|                  from core/utils.c:1:
| In function 'strncat',
|     inlined from 'uwsgi_substitute' at core/utils.c:1732:2:
| /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:136:10: error: '__builtin_strncat'     output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
|   136 |   return __builtin___strncat_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_substitute':
| core/utils.c:1732:2: note: length computed here
|  1732 |  strncat(dst, ptr, strlen(ptr));
|       |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
| + bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + [ -p /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/    uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/temp/fifo.16498 ]
| + printf %b\0 bbfatal_log 'python setup.py install --root=/home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/build-xwayland/tmp/work/    cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/uwsgi/2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0/image     --prefix=/usr     --install-lib=/usr/lib/    python2.7/site-packages     --install-data=/usr/share' execution failed.
| + exit 1
| + bb_exit_handler
| + ret=1
| + echo WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| + exit 1
| 
NOTE: recipe uwsgi-2.0.14+gitAUTOINC+af44211739-r0: task do_install: Failed
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1904 tasks of which 1903 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/eldorado/yocto/imx6ulevk_zeus/sources/meta-cloud-services/meta-openstack/recipes-extended/uwsgi/uwsgi_git.bb:do_install
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Anyone found this behavior/error in zeus build?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an observation, This NOT happen in Yocto SUMO branch,

Comment: I found a possible reason for the fail, it maybe is derived from a gcc version update as described in: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1819 and https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/commit/d4bea14c2a2ebb2fa6fddbe7b40b00266780366d
I note in the uwsgi_git.bb file that the version branch used is 2.0, So I will try update to 2.1 version